# I Have a UDP Server and Client , now how to let them continuously send/recieve?

Tags: java, server, udp, client, chat

So as the brief title says, I have a a UDP Server and Client. The server has 3 methods at the moment, one to open the socket and receive a packet. The next Reads the packet and prints the information. The final creates a response packet from the user input.

I'll include my server code here as I think if I can get help with making the server be able to send and receive I can convert my new knowledge to the client side as well!

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ServerChat {

DatagramSocket Server = null;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];     
DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);


//Opens the socket to receive the packet
public void createAndListen() throws SocketException, IOException{
    Server = new DatagramSocket(9876);     
    Server.receive(incomingPacket);
}

//Simply converts the packet to a string and then prints the message

public void read(){
    String message = new String(incomingPacket.getData());
    System.out.println("Client: " + message);
}


//This methhod will allow the user to print a message to be sent back to the client

public void send() throws IOException{
    System.out.print("Server: ");

    //Receiving input

    BufferedReader response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String reply = response.readLine();

    //Getting recipent information

    InetAddress IPAddress = incomingPacket.getAddress();
    int port = incomingPacket.getPort();
    byte[] data = reply.getBytes();

    //Crafting and sending the packet

    DatagramPacket replyPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPAddress, port);
    Server.send(replyPacket);  

}




public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerChat Server = new ServerChat();
    Server.createAndListen();
    Server.read();
    Server.send();


}
```

Thanks for any help!
Quick edit because rereading it doesnt seem clear; the server does initate and listen, then receives a packet sent from the client, and can respond. After one send and receive both Client and Server close though and thats what im trying to prevent i'd like them to remain open to communicate again. I understand that UDP is not continuous connection so I think its more of I need the Server to be able to consistently receive packets as well as send them.

Edit 2: I recoded my client to do a continuous loop listening on the port, and it will work one message at a time. now i just need to it send/receive continuous! will make a different post about it though as i changed from multiple different methods to one method with a while loop.

Comment: You need to post your current code. If you receive in a loop and send in a loop, you must get continous throughput. So clearly you haven't done that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must:
- split createAndListen() into two methods: the socket must be initialized only once and you must loop on receive(). 
- then reformulate your code and methods.

```
main 
    init socket     // only once
    while(some-condition)     // receive loop
        receive()   // this is a blocking method
        reply()     // and send()
    close socket
end
```

Afterwards there will be some major improvements to add to your code to make it more efficient and robust. Check out Google for good materials about Java Socket Programming and Good practices.

Comment: I actually reprogrammed my server side to do excatly what you had said, i initialize the socket outside the loop, then have a loop receiving and sending. It limits it to only receiving one message and replying to one message at a time though, do you have any thoughts as to how i would be able to send and receive continuously?

Comment: You should be able to receive packets at a decent rate as soon as you receiver is able to treat incoming messages at the rate they are sent by the sender. For your tests, setup your "client" to send at a decent rate (put some sleep() or stick to request-reply for synchronization) and of course don't ask user input (that blocks your program!) when you treat incoming messages. The next is step is generally to wrap the message processing and derived actions that are slow or block execution into a thread. Eg. "submit" the heavy logic to the thread pool of an executor service.

Comment: Also for advanced performance you will have to consider Non-Blocking IOs (NIO) and frameworks like Netty. But I think it's a little early for that. I suggest you try and know more by yourself as such topics can be the subject of a whole course or book. First focus on Blocking-IOs (the classic way, and generally enough for simple use cases).